# Inner join and Union within report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have 3 tables first table named memberform with columns id and name:

```
 id   name
 12   john
```

In the second table (named imat_statistic) I have descriptions:

```
 id     description 
 12     Blue with brown
```

In the third table (named Vivl_Statistic) I have the same columns:

```
id      description
12      green with yellow
```

I want to get this result:

```
john    blue with brown
john    green with yellow
```

I tried using the wizard to link ID from memberform with imat_statistc, ID and vivl_statistic, ID. But nothing was appeared in my report. I also need to include the description in the same stele.

Answer (score 0):

```
(select memberform .name, imat_statistic.description from test inner join
    test1 on memberform .id = imat_statistic.id) 
union all 
(select memberform .name, Vivl_Statistic.description from test inner join
    test3 on memberform .id = Vivl_Statistic.id) ;
```

While connecting to the data source, click on Add Command and enter this query.  Use the name and description fields in your report.